# apache velocity refuses to work with virgo

Tags: jakarta-ee, osgi, velocity, eclipse-virgo

I've been working my way through virgo configuration issues on a project, and there is one library that just refuses to cooperate - apache velocity.

My bundle's manifest is thus (I've changed or removed the names of some internal libraries):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Web-ContextPath: blah
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: thebundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: blahblah
Bundle-Version: 0.1.0
Bundle-Activator: blah.Activator
Import-Package: mydatasource,
 javax.crypto,
 javax.jms;version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)",
 javax.naming;version=0,
 javax.naming.directory;version=0,
 javax.servlet;version="[2.6.0,2.6.0]",
 javassist.util.proxy;version="[3.15.0.GA,3.15.0.GA]",
 javax.servlet.http;version="[2.6.0,2.6.0]",
 org.hibernate.validator;version="[4.2.0.Final,4.2.0.Final]",
 org.osgi.framework;version="[1.7.0,1.7.0]",
 org.osgi.util.tracker,
 org.slf4j.impl;version="[1.7.2,1.7.2]"
Export-Package: .... (stuff removed)
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 WEB-INF/classes,
 WEB-INF/lib/velocity.jar <--- THIS IS APACHE VELOCITY
 WEB-INF/lib/blahblah.jar
Import-Bundle: org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm;version="3.5.0.RELEASE";resolution:=optional,
 a bunch of other bundles I've removed
```

And I get the following exception at the end of a long stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.equinox.KernelBundleClassLoader.loadClass(KernelBundleClassLoader.java:135)
```

I've verified that the velocity.jar gets published in my bundle.  I'm not having any issues with any other libraries.  It appears to see some classes in velocity but not others.  I've tried bringing all of the individual velocity packages in under Import-Package, no effect. I've tried harsh language, no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import the bundle and the package into your bundle, (before you can download the velocity bundle and deploy into your pickup folder)

```
see this example 


Import-Bundle:
 org.springframework.web.servlet;version="[3.0.0.RELEASE,3.0.5.RELEASE]"
 com.springsource.org.apache.velocity;version="[1.5.0,1.5.0]"

Import-Package:
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity;version="[3.0, 3.5)"

 Import-Bundle: com.springsource.javax.ejb;version="[3.0.0,3.0.0]",com.
 springsource.org.apache.catalina;version="[7.0.26,7.0.26]",com.spring
source.org.apache.commons.lang;version="[2.6.0,2.6.0]",com.springsour
ce.org.apache.velocity;version="[1.5.0,1.5.0]",org.eclipse.virgo.web.
dm;version="[3.0.3.RELEASE,3.0.3.RELEASE]",org.springframework.contex
t;version="[3.0.5.RELEASE,3.0.5.RELEASE]",org.springframework.web;ver
 sion="[3.0.5.RELEASE,3.0.5.RELEASE]",**org.springframework.web.servlet;
version="[3.0.0.RELEASE,3.0.5.RELEASE]"**
Bundle-Vendor: Roshka
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_37
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: helloworld-bundlor
Import-Package: javax.ejb,org.apache.commons.lang,org.apache.naming.ja
va,org.apache.velocity,org.apache.velocity.servlet,org.eclipse.virgo.
web.dm;version="[3.0.0, 4.0.0)",org.springframework.beans.factory.ann
otation;version="[3.0, 3.5)",org.springframework.context,org.springfr
amework.core.io;version="[3.0, 3.5)",org.springframework.ejb.access,o
rg.springframework.stereotype;version="[3.0, 3.5)",org.springframewor
k.web.bind.annotation;version="[3.0, 3.5)",org.springframework.web.co
ntext;version="[3.0, 3.5)",org.springframework.web.servlet;version="[
  3.0, 3.5)",org.springframework.web.servlet.view;version="[3.0, 3.5)",
**org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity;version="[3.0, 3.5)",or 
g.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation;version="[3.0, 3.5)"
```

Comment: yep, this was it.  I'd figured it out months ago, of course :)

Comment: I still could not do my project work with velocity, I have other issues that I will post for help. You get to work with Virgo velocity? regards.